# How would I write a script that allows specific users in google sheets access to a bulk amount of hyperlinks within a sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to write a script that gives dynamic access to hyperlinks as they populate in a column.

Ei as more rows/columns are populated from a query Id like the computer to grant viewing assess.

Ive manually been providing access as my queries pull in new rows/columns(instances)

Id like the output to be that a manager can be granted access to a files hyperlink based on the access granted in his/her manager sheet.

Comment: How about just sharing the spreadsheet with specific users

Comment: By dynamic does that mean you are hoping to take them away?

Comment: Welcome. Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested on [ask].